# Vue3: `computed` is evaluated on change in any field of `props`, even unused one

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have Vue3 component with three properties:

```js
const props = defineProps<{
    begin: number,
    end: number,
    pos: number,
}>()
```

`begin` and `end` are used to fetch data from server and `pos` is used for plain visualisation purposes:

```js
const url = computed(() => `...&begin=${begin}&end=${end}`)
const {data} = useFetch(url).json()
```

However, data are fetched every time `pos` parameter is changed.

In principle, this may be solved with watchers and manual fields comparison, but is seems very cumbersome.

What is the most elegant way to prevent unneeded fetches?

Comment: What's useFetch? In case it's vueuse, the question should explain it. It's unclear what's the case with pos. It's not used in the code you posted. Please, clarify, how exactly its changes should affect fetch

Comment: useFetch comes from Nuxt

Answer (score 0):

It's actually caused of your useFetch and not cause of the properties being refreshed. If your properties don't play a role in your computed, it won't refresh.

However, if you still want to use it, you can just verify before you fetch that your const {data} is well initialized and if it's the case not refetch with no reason.